# Can a HAML file be imported into another HAML file?

Tags: haml

I have a number of `haml` files, many of which have the same variable declared/set. I'd like to be able to change the value of that variable in once place. I would like to have one `haml` file where I declare and set all the variables, then have N `haml` files that import the shared-variables file to actually consume the values. I am not using any framework, and do not want to convert the app to use another framework. Is it possible to import `haml` files into other `haml` files like I am trying to do without additional frameworks?

Gem install command:

```
sudo gem install haml
```

Terminal build command:

```
haml index.haml index.html
```

**Goal Structure:**

*shared-variables.haml*

```
- country = "United States"
```

*index.haml*

```
import shared-variables.haml # does not work - just illustrating what I'd like to do
!!!
%html{
    lang: "en"
}
    %head
        %title #{country}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution that works, but I am still interested in hearing if there are any better practices. Here is the solution I came up with:

1. Create a shared-variables ruby file
2. Create a public DATA module
3. Define the variables I want in the DATA module
4. In the haml template, import the ruby file
5. Reference the DATA module in the haml file to get the variable values

**shared-variables.rb**

```
module DATA
    COUNTRY = "2021-09-11"
end
```

**index.haml**

```
:ruby
    require_relative "shared-variables"

!!!
%html
    %head
        %title #{DATA::COUNTRY}
```